# Teradata Fastload - Sequential order from flat file

Tags: teradata

A flat file is being ingested into Teradata staging area using Fastload utility. Post this process, a merge operation will be done on this data which will insert/update into a target table, based on the latest timestamp. I encountered a problem when the timestamp was same for a customer. Let me explain that using the following data in the flat file:

Cust1 | 123 | 15-May-2018 13:01:01
Cust1 | 234 | 15-May-2018 13:01:01
Cust2 | 111 | 15-May-2018 13:02:01

This is the order of data in the flat file. As you can see, both records of Cust1 has same timestamp. But The second record in the flat file is the latest, since the sequential write has written this record in the second row.
How do i fetch this record to be used in the MERGE statement? Currently my MERGE statement partitioned this based on the TIMESTAMP value. Is there anyway to find the sequential order when fastload runs? or some kind of row_id to used ?

Comment: There's only one solution I can think of: create the staging table with an identity column and load using a single FastLoad session (this used to assign the sequence based on the input order, I doubt it changed)

Comment: I think you would need to use the customer column as your PI, to guarantee all rows for a given customer are on the same amp.  Otherwise your identity column will be useless.  I'm not convinced even that would work.  I'd use a simple script to modify the file, to add a row number.

Comment: Is there a way you can preprocess this file and append a sequence number to each record in the file? It doesn’t have to reset when the first field changes. When you load the data into the table you should be able  use a `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_ID, {timestamp field} ORDER BY {sequence field} DESC) = 1`. Without seeing the rest of your MERGE statement, I cannot tell how you’d stitch this in, but I think you could do it with a derived table.